# Android padding in XML is different to .setPadding() programatically

Tags: android, padding

if I use padding within a XML layout, my background image is a little bit smaller than if I do the layout programatically an use .setPadding() on my imageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivBackgroundStartUp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:alpha="0.30"
    android:src="@drawable/start"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and programatically...

```
    this.mContext = activity;

//      RELATIVE LAYOUT
RelativeLayout rlMain = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
rlMain.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
rlMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

//      HINTERGRUNDBILD
ImageView ivBG = new ImageView(mContext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
ivBG.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
ivBG.setAlpha(0.30f);
ivBG.setPadding(15,0,15,0);
rlMain.addView(ivBG);
```

both times i´d set padding to left, right / 15, 15 but the result is different.
Maybe anybody knows why...

Comment: I think programatically you are creating relative layout inside relative  layout and image view is inside an inner relative layout while from xml you are creating image view inside main relative layout only or you havent used ralative layout rlp anywhere or is this  complete code ?.

Comment: no, the layout hierarchy is the same... both solutions have a top relativeLayout in front of the imageView. this code is not complete but the following elements are not essential. If I reduce the code on the top layout and the imageView, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, when you give the padding programatically, you are giving it in `int` which is taken as `pixels`. And, when you are giving in `XML` you are giving it as `dp` which is `Density-independent pixel`. So the values are changed.

If you want it to be the same. Try something like this in the XML.

```
android:paddingRight="15px"
```

If you want to specify programatically, without changing the XML and want the output to be the same. You must convert, `px` to `dp` and then use.

Answer (score -2):

Shaik MD Ashiq is right. To solve this problem programatically I have to use this code...

```
    //      BACKGROUND
ImageView ivBG = new ImageView(mContext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
ivBG.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
ivBG.setAlpha(0.30f);

float scale = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int densityPix = (int) (15 * scale + 0.5f);

ivBG.setPadding(densityPix, 0, densityPix, 0);
rlMain.addView(ivBG);
```